# Set the Content-Type when using Ajax.BeginForm

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have a simple ViewModel:

```
public class CategoryViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Category ID")]
    [Editable(false)]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required")]
    [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 2, ErrorMessage = "You must enter a category name of at least 2 and maximum 100 characters")]
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
}
```

I have a controller which send to the view and new, non-populated, viewmodel with CategoryId and ParentId set to 0. My view was using @Html.EditorFor using the viewmodel (custom object.cshtml editor template), but to keep things easy, I changed it following simple:

```
var options = new AjaxOptions()
{
    Url = "/Api/Category/Post/"
    OnComplete = "onCategorySaveComplete(xhr, status)",
    OnBegin = "onCategorySaveBegin",
    OnFailure = "onCategorySaveFailure(xhr, status)",
};  
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(options))
{
    <div class="inputForm">
        <div class="header">@(Model.CategoryId == 0 ? "New Category" : "Edit "+Model.Name+" ("+Model.CategoryId+"/"+Model.ParentId+")")</div>
                <div class="section">
                    <input type="hidden" name="CategoryId" value="" data-bind="value: CategoryId" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="ParentId" value="" data-bind="value: ParentId" />
                    <div class="line">
                        <div class="label">
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name) *
                        </div>
                        <div class="input">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name,null,new {@data_bind = "value: Name"})
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        @Html.ValidationSummary("Some data is not correct:")
        <div class="footer"> <input type="submit" id="btnSave" value="Save" /></div>
    </div>
}
```

In my API controller, I have:

```
public CategoryViewModel Post(CategoryViewModel value)
{
    value = CategoryService.AddOrUpdate(value);
    return value;
}
```

I have other client side functions which will allow user to select a category from a KendoUI treeview, which loads the ViewModel via API call, and uses KnockOut to to bindings, but that all works nicely, so let me skip that for now.

Now, when I submit the form and look at what is sent to the server, I see the following:

```
Key Value
Request POST /Api/Category/Post/ HTTP/1.1
Accept  */*
Content-Type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
Referer http://localhost:3709/Category/
Accept-Language en-GB,nl-BE;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)
Host    localhost:3709
Content-Length  71
Connection  Keep-Alive
Cache-Control   no-cache
Cookie  GUEST_LANGUAGE_ID=en_US; COOKIE_SUPPORT=true
```

and the request body:

```
CategoryId=1130&ParentId=4&Name=Sensors&X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest
```

Up to now, all normal I guess. But I add a breakpoint in my API controller and here I see that my CategoryViewModel value actually holds only "Name" and "ParentId", and that "CategoryId" is 0
My service then thinks it needs to create a new Category which it does, returns a new CategoryViewModel which is then returned to the client is JSON string.

I cannot understand why my CategoryId is not read into my ViewModel. Also, I have cracked my head on trying to submit the data via JSON string and not in URLEcoded manner. 
Should I simple step away from the helpers and use jquery directly?

Many thanks for your help

EDIT After night sleep:

The reason why my CategoryId is not being read into my ViewModel is so simple: CategoryId has an annotation of [Editable(false)]
If I remove that, works. I actually use these annotations only for the EditorFor and validation messages, without realizing it would block an actual write to the field.

So I need another way to tell EditorFor to render a certain fields as hidden html field. Any idea's?
And why using @Ajax.BeginForm can't be configured to send a JSON string to server instead of url encoded, that remains too.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> So I need another way to tell EditorFor to render a certain fields as hidden html field. Any idea's?

You could use the [`HiddenInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.hiddeninputattribute.aspx) attribute which will instruct the editor template to render it as a hidden field:

```
[HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
public int CategoryId { get; set; }
```